# How are Bukkit Event listener methods run?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

When coding a Minecraft plugin in java, you can create an event listener method, and name it whatever you want, but you have to pass in the class of the event listener, for example:

```
@EventListener
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
     // code here
}
```

I am just wondering, how is this method executed 'behind the scenes', if the name of the method is not known by any class in the Bukkit API? I hope I explained myself well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When registering an instance that implements `Listener`, Bukkit will use reflection to check every method in that class with the `@EventHandler` annotation and with one argument that extends `Event`. It will be stored in a registry and will be called when the event occurs.

Edit: The source code below may be of interest to you. [Source](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPluginLoader.java#237)

```
@Override
@NotNull
public Map<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>> createRegisteredListeners(@NotNull Listener listener, @NotNull final Plugin plugin) {
    Validate.notNull(plugin, "Plugin can not be null");
    Validate.notNull(listener, "Listener can not be null");

    boolean useTimings = server.getPluginManager().useTimings();
    Map<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>> ret = new HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>>();
    Set<Method> methods;
    try {
        Method[] publicMethods = listener.getClass().getMethods();
        Method[] privateMethods = listener.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        methods = new HashSet<Method>(publicMethods.length + privateMethods.length, 1.0f);
        for (Method method : publicMethods) {
            methods.add(method);
        }
        for (Method method : privateMethods) {
            methods.add(method);
        }
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        plugin.getLogger().severe("Plugin " + plugin.getDescription().getFullName() + " has failed to register events for " + listener.getClass() + " because " + e.getMessage() + " does not exist.");
        return ret;
    }

    for (final Method method : methods) {
        final EventHandler eh = method.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class);
        if (eh == null) continue;
        // Do not register bridge or synthetic methods to avoid event duplication
        // Fixes SPIGOT-893
        if (method.isBridge() || method.isSynthetic()) {
            continue;
        }
        final Class<?> checkClass;
        if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 1 || !Event.class.isAssignableFrom(checkClass = method.getParameterTypes()[0])) {
            plugin.getLogger().severe(plugin.getDescription().getFullName() + " attempted to register an invalid EventHandler method signature \"" + method.toGenericString() + "\" in " + listener.getClass());
            continue;
        }
        final Class<? extends Event> eventClass = checkClass.asSubclass(Event.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Set<RegisteredListener> eventSet = ret.get(eventClass);
        if (eventSet == null) {
            eventSet = new HashSet<RegisteredListener>();
            ret.put(eventClass, eventSet);
        }

        for (Class<?> clazz = eventClass; Event.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz); clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) {
            // This loop checks for extending deprecated events
            if (clazz.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) != null) {
                Warning warning = clazz.getAnnotation(Warning.class);
                WarningState warningState = server.getWarningState();
                if (!warningState.printFor(warning)) {
                    break;
                }
                plugin.getLogger().log(
                        Level.WARNING,
                        String.format(
                                "\"%s\" has registered a listener for %s on method \"%s\", but the event is Deprecated. \"%s\"; please notify the authors %s.",
                                plugin.getDescription().getFullName(),
                                clazz.getName(),
                                method.toGenericString(),
                                (warning != null && warning.reason().length() != 0) ? warning.reason() : "Server performance will be affected",
                                Arrays.toString(plugin.getDescription().getAuthors().toArray())),
                        warningState == WarningState.ON ? new AuthorNagException(null) : null);
                break;
            }
        }

        EventExecutor executor = new EventExecutor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NotNull Listener listener, @NotNull Event event) throws EventException {
                try {
                    if (!eventClass.isAssignableFrom(event.getClass())) {
                        return;
                    }
                    method.invoke(listener, event);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    throw new EventException(ex.getCause());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    throw new EventException(t);
                }
            }
        };
        if (useTimings) {
            eventSet.add(new TimedRegisteredListener(listener, executor, eh.priority(), plugin, eh.ignoreCancelled()));
        } else {
            eventSet.add(new RegisteredListener(listener, executor, eh.priority(), plugin, eh.ignoreCancelled()));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```